# Android JUnit4 Test not calling Super Constructor Method

Tags: java, android, junit

I have a class that extends and ArrayAdapter. when I run the code everything works fine and things function. However, when I run the JUnit tests I have noticed that the super method is not running the constructor properly and mObjects (in the super class) is not being set to the values of objects as it should.

the getCount() method consistently return 0 regardless of the input.

What do I need to do in order to get this to function properly with Tests?

**Java Class**

```
public class PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private BiMap<Integer, String> map;
    private Set<Integer> mPendingItems, mDoneItems;
    private boolean isSuperUser;

    public PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, BiMap<Integer, String> mapping) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        isSuperUser = false;
        mPendingItems = new HashSet<>();
        mDoneItems = new HashSet<>();
        map = mapping;
    }
...
```

**Test**

I am attempting to test it with JUnit

```
public class PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapterTest  extends AndroidTestCase {
    PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter mAdapter;
    List<String> values;

    Context mContext;

    public PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapterTest(){
        super();

//        mContext = new MockContext().createPackageContext(new CallBellApplication().getPackageName(), MockContext.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        mContext = new MockContext();
        new POCValues(mContext);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
//        super.setUp();

        setContext(mContext);
        testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly();

        values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("one");
        values.add("two");
        values.add("three");

        mAdapter = new PlanOfCareCheckBoxAdapter(mContext, 0, values, POCValues.masterMap);
        // assertEquals("one", mAdapter.getItem(0));
    }
```

Comment: why do you think it is not calling `super`?

Comment: When I run with debug statements directly after super is called I can see that all the inherited values are set at runtime. However these same values are not set during the testing

Comment: Did you debug your test and you see values is not set?

Comment: yes. the Context and list are not set. But again only when I run the test